# Rspec not catching purposeful failure

Tags: ruby, exception, rspec

I'm trying to check that one of my class methods responds to invalid input with an exception, but Rspec isn't having it.

My class file:

```
class WhateverClass
  def run(options)
    if options['input'].nil? || options['input'].empty?
      fail ArgumentError, 'No input object provided in configuration.'
    end
  end
end
```

My Rspec test:

```
RSpec.describe WhateverClass do
  it 'should raise an ArgumentError when provided invalid input' do
    invalid_input = { 'nonsense' => 'here' }
    expect(WhateverClass.new.run(invalid_input)).to raise_error(ArgumentError)
  end
end
```

The result of running the above test is this:

```
1) WhateverClass should raise an ArgumentError when provided invalid input
   Failure/Error: expect(WhateverClass.new.run(invalid_input)).to raise_error(ArgumentError)
   ArgumentError:
     No input object provided in configuration.
   # ./whatever_class.rb:9:in `run'
   # ./spec/whatever_class_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Finished in 0.00048 seconds (files took 1.51 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure
```

===================================================

Note that if I do something like this:

```
RSpec.describe WhateverClass do
  it 'should raise an ArgumentError when provided invalid input' do
    expect{ fail ArgumentError }.to raise_error(ArgumentError)
    invalid_input = { 'nonsense' => 'here' }
    expect(WhateverClass.new.run(invalid_input)).to raise_error(ArgumentError)
  end
end
```

the first expect passes, but the second expect fails.

How can I get this test to function properly?

Answer (score 16):

Turns out that changing it from:

```
expect(WhateverClass.new.run(invalid_input)).to raise_error(ArgumentError)
```

to:

```
expect { WhateverClass.new.run(invalid_input) }.to raise_error(ArgumentError)
```

fixed the issue. Hopefully this helps somebody else.

Answer (score 9):

Switching to the block form of `expect` is the right thing to do but I think a bit of explanation is worthwhile.

When you say:

```
expect(WhateverClass.new.run(invalid_input)).to ...
```

you're effectively saying:

```
x = WhateverClass.new.run(invalid_input)
expect(x).to ...
```

so `WhateverClass.new.run(invalid_input)` will be evaluated while the arguments to `expect` are being built (i.e. *before* `expect` is called). That means that the exception is raised before `expect` can do anything.

When you say:

```
expect { WhateverClass.new.run(invalid_input) }.to ...
```

you're giving `expect` a block (`{ WhateverClass.new.run(invalid_input) }`) and `expect` will execute the block after it has set up its exception handling. That means that the exception will be raised while `expect`'s exception handler is in place so the exception will be trapped and the `to` method on `expect`'s return value will be executed.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation.  It's unfortunately very easy to overlook the difference between () and {} in the Rspec docs.  This seems like a footgun that Rspec could provide better warnings about on their raise_error() page, since other Rspec example pages use expect().